# Why does my number of transactions isn't exactly the same between my default channel grouping and my custom channel grouping ?

Tags: google-analytics

I've a simple question and everything is in the title : Why does my number of transactions isn't exactly the same between my default channel grouping and my custom channel grouping ?

Even if the discrepancies if very limited I would like to know why...

I guess it's because of sampling or something like this... but I can't find any officiel statement about this...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of sampling data in Google Analytics.

1. It also could because there are on or more filters in your custom channel grouping.
2. Maybe you have different attribution models in your channel

Comment: thanks Arthur. what do you mean when you say "there are one or more filters"... filter are applied at a view level so they are supposed to be the same for the custom and default channel grouping. Also I don't understand your second point.

Comment: In your analytics account, on the right (View) on the administration panel, you will find the fifth label "Filters". So maybe on your view there is a filter that could affect one ore several of your channel.

What i mean for the second point is that, maybe on transaction could be in several channel on your custom channel grouping. For example in _brand_ and in _PPC Brand_ : it's just an hypothesis.